# Questions about how to split and assign values ​in a list (Python/Spark)

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, dataset

I have the following dataset:

```
list = [{'id': 1, 'source': [1,2], 'segment': ['a1','b1']},
        {'id': 2, 'source': [3], 'segment': ['c1']},
        {'id': 3, 'source': [4,5,6,7], 'segment': ['d1', 'e1', 'f1']},
        {'id': 4, 'source': [8,9], 'segment': ['g1']}]
```

However, there is the following problem: segment a1 generated segment b1, while segment d1 generated e1, which in turn generated f1. So where there is more than one value in the segment key, I need to separate, and assign the segment as the source. however the sources cannot be separated. When splitting the data, I can separate each segment into a line, but I need to replace the source, for example:

{id:1, font:[1,2], segment: [a1]}, {id:1, font: [a1], segment:[b1]}, ..., {id:3, font: [ 4,5,6,7], segment: [d1]}, {id:3, source: [d1], segment: [e1]}

Does anyone have an idea of ​​how to start solving this?

-------------------EDIT
Sorry if my question was vague, it's my first time on the platform!

Let's try again:

This is the output I currently get from a system:

```
list = [{'id': 1, 'source': [1,2], 'segment': ['a1','b1']},
        {'id': 2, 'source': [3], 'segment': ['c1']},
        {'id': 3, 'source': [4,5,6,7], 'segment': ['d1', 'e1', 'f1']},
        {'id': 4, 'source': [8,9], 'segment': ['g1']}]
```

However, I needed to separate the elements where there was more than one segment output, like [a1,b1], so that it looks like this:

```
list1 = [{'id': 1, 'source': [1,2], 'segment': ['a1']},
{'id': 1, 'source': ['a1'], 'segment': ['b1']},
{'id': 2, 'source': [3], 'segment': ['c1']},
{'id': 3, 'source': [4,5,6,7], 'segment': ['d1']},
{'id': 3, 'source': ['d1'], 'segment': ['e1']},
{'id': 3, 'source': ['e1'], 'segment': ['f1']},
{'id': 4, 'source': [8,9], 'segment': ['g1']}]
```

I tried to do this with pandas and spark, but without success.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand the problem description. What do you mean when you say that one segment "generated" another? How is that fact reflected in the data, and why does it matter? What actually is a "segment", and what do you mean about "separating" it "into a line"? Also, what does this question have to do with either Pandas DataFrames, or Apache Spark? Why tag the question this way?

Comment: Sorry if my question was vague, I'll comment below again, trying to explain better

Comment: So when there is more than one value in `segment`, you want to make a separate dict for each element of `segment`? And when you do the separation, the rule is that the `source` for the first value in `segment` should be the original value, and the `source` for each other value should be the previous value? I still don't understand what this has to do with either Pandas or Spark. It looks straightforward to me to write code for that with just the builtins and I can't imagine how those libraries would help.

Comment: The question that remains for me is, what actually do you find difficult about the task? *How* did you "try to do this"? What do you imagine are the logical steps that need to be taken to solve the problem, and where do you get stuck when trying to implement them? What goes wrong with the code?